# Stack Exchange "Twelve Days of Christmas"

Tags: discussion, fun

This network has given so much to me over the years and I want to give a little something back. Whether that's a good thing or not...is for the community to decide with the triangle buttons. Without further ado, I grant to you:

> **The Stack Exchange Days of Christmas**
>
> *adapted by World Engineer*
>
> On the First Day of Christmas, Stack Exchange gave to me, a user
>   called Community♦.
>
> On the Second Day of Christmas, Stack Exchange gave to me, two Gold
>   Badges and a user called Community♦.
>
> On the Third Day of Christmas, Stack Exchange gave to me, three
>   teen Mods, two Gold Badges and a user called Community♦.
>
> On the Fourth Day of Christmas, Stack Exchange gave to me, four close
>   votes, , three teen Mods, two Gold Badges and a user called
>   Community♦.
>
> On the Fifth Day of Christmas, Stack Exchange gave to me, five chat
>   pings, four close votes, , three teen Mods, two Gold Badges and a
>   user called Community♦.
>
> On the Sixth Day of Christmas, Stack Exchange gave to me, six meta
>   posts, five chat pings, four close votes, , three teen Mods, two
>   Gold Badges and a user called Community♦.
>
> On the Seventh Day of Christmas, Stack Exchange gave to me, seven silent
>   downvotes, six meta posts, five chat pings, four close votes, , three
>   teen Mods, two Gold Badges and a user called Community♦.
>
> On the Eighth Day of Christmas, Stack Exchange gave to me, eight help
>   vampires, seven silent downvotes, six meta posts, five chat pings,
>   four close votes, , three teen Mods, two Gold Badges and a user
>   called Community♦.
>
> On the Ninth Day of Christmas, Stack Exchange gave to me, nine
>   spammers spamming, eight help vampires, seven silent downvotes, six
>   meta posts, five chat pings, four close votes, , three teen Mods,
>   two Gold Badges and a user called Community♦.
>
> On the Tenth Day of Christmas, Stack Exchange gave to me, ten Bridge
>   stars, nine spammers spamming, eight help vampires, seven silent
>   downvotes, six meta posts, five chat pings, four close votes, , three
>   teen Mods, two Gold Badges and a user called Community♦.
>
> On the Eleventh Day of Christmas, Stack Exchange gave to me, eleven
>   thousand views, ten Bridge stars, nine spammers spamming, eight help
>   vampires, seven silent downvotes, six meta posts, five chat pings,
>   four close votes, , three teen Mods, two Gold Badges and a user
>   called Community♦.
>
> On the Twelfth Day of Christmas, Stack Exchange gave to me, twelve
>   hats for free, eleven thousand views, ten Bridge stars, nine spammers
>   spamming, eight help vampires, seven silent downvotes, six meta posts,
>   five chat pings, four close votes, , three teen Mods, two Gold
>   Badges and a user called Community♦.

Comment: Wait, why wouldn't you put gold badges where golden rings go? Seems like the most logical place for them.

Comment: You’re a good person! Have a sensational day.

Comment: @animuson I'm guessing because "pings" rhymes with "rings."

Comment: The rhyme is one part, Gold Badges tend to be scarcer on non-Trilogy sites so the two seemed appropriate.

Comment: -1: Cute, but you're really reaching with a few of those.

Answer (score 8):

Looks good, but I have a couple of edits to make:

> On the Ninth Day of Christmas, Stack Exchange gave to me, **nine Shogs-a-Shogging**, eight help vampires, seven silent downvotes, six meta posts, five chat pings, four close votes, **three scrblnrds a scrabbling**, two Gold Badges and a user called Community♦.
>
> On the Third Day of Christmas, Stack Exchange gave to me, **three scrblnrds a scrabbling**, two Gold Badges and a user called Community♦.

Comment: You just missed one hat. ;)

Comment: what hat is that?

Comment: I'm not supposed to reveal the name, because I'm not listening!

Comment: That's a funny phrase, "supposed to"

Comment: You could have gotten a hat... anyway, I'm not listening (hint hint) to this

Comment: Oh. meh, it was a good edit, so I accepted it

Answer (score 5):

Ask and they answer
Does knowledge grow on trees, or
Is it human-made?